# What is the most efficient way to edit the values in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have multiple dictionaries inside the list, what is an efficient and possible way to update and limit all the float values to only two decimal points?
For example: Make the value of `'AmazonEC2': 22.740000000000002` to `'AmazonEC2': 22.74`

```
[{
  'AmazonEC2': 22.740000000000002,
  'awskms': 0.09,
  'AmazonDynamoDB': 6.740000000000002,
  'AmazonElastiCache': 0.01,
  'AmazonS3': 5.54,
  'AmazonCloudWatch': 1.08,
  'AWSAmplify': 0.55,
  'AmazonRDS': 0.01
}, {
  'awskms': 0.740000000000003,
  'AmazonS3': 5.740000000000004,
  'AmazonCloudWatch': 1.740000000000003,
  'AmazonDynamoDB': 6.740000000000006,
  'AmazonEC2': 22.740000000000002,
  'AWSAmplify': 0.49,
  'AmazonRDS': 0.01,
  'AmazonElastiCache': 0.01
}]
```

Comment: Simply iterating over and rounding them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for item in your_list:
    for key in item.keys():
        item[key] = round(item[key], 2)
```

The main iteration is list, dict lookup is `O(1)`.